# How to set different colorPrimary, colorAccent... for each Xamarin.Forms Page? C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I know that to set a customized color for a property, we have to set it in style.xml file, but I want to have different color properties for each of my Xamarin.Forms page. How can I archive this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>
    
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Your code shows `Xamarin.Android` styling. But you ask about `Xamarin.Forms` pages. Don't need a style.xml file, for that. Don't need to work with those "android" properties. I recommend a [`ResourceDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries) on each page. See that doc and follow its link to the related sample code.

Comment: Appreciated your advice. i will check out the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xamarin.forms, you could set the resource for each page like below.

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="xxx">
            <Setter Property="" Value=""></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Or you could set the resource in App.xaml.cs:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="color1">AliceBlue</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then use it in each page.

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource color1}">
        ......
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Mr. Wendy, for Entry property, can i change the color of the underline when the entry is being input by the user?

Comment: i have tested out your code. it works fine, but i am trying to find the Underline color of Entry in the setter.

Comment: If you want to change the underline of entry, you could do this in custom renderer. But it could not changed when the entry is being input. Add the code below in `OnElementChanged` method.  `Control.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);`